# Duplicate array without doubling peak memory usage in PHP

Tags: php, memory

I'm looking for the most memory efficient way to process each element in a large PHP array that is already in memory and convert it to another format with minimal peak memory usage increase and without writing data out to disk.

My initial thought was as I loop through the $source_array, I could simply unset() each row to free up memory. However that actually increases the peak memory usage.

Below is example code to showcase the situation:

```
$source_array = array_fill( 0, 500000, [ 'col1' => 'val1', 'col2' => 'val2', 'col3' => 'val3', 'col4' => 'val4', 'col5' => 'val5',] );
echo "Initial Memory Usage: ". memory_get_usage()  .' Peak Memory Usage: '. memory_get_peak_usage() ."<br>\n";

$destination_array = [];
foreach( $source_array as $key => $row ) {
    $destination_array[$key] = $row; //Assume some manipulation of $row here.

    //$source_array[$key] = null; //Causes peak memory to increase.
    //unset( $source_array[$key] ); //Causes peak memory to increase
    if ( $key > 0 && $key % 100000 == 0 ) {
        echo "  $key. Inside Loop Memory Usage: ". memory_get_usage()  .' Inside Loop Peak Memory Usage: '. memory_get_peak_usage() ."<br>\n"; //Peak memory usage is double initial memory usage.
        gc_collect_cycles();
    }
}
unset( $source_array );
echo "Final Memory Usage: ". memory_get_usage()  .' Final Peak Memory Usage: '. memory_get_peak_usage() ."<br>\n"; //Peak memory usage is double initial memory usage.
```

> Output: **NOTICE** Initial and Final memory usage are identical, but peak memory is double.
>
> Initial Memory Usage: 17250856 Peak Memory Usage: 17250952
> 100000. Inside Loop Memory Usage: 21449400 Inside Loop Peak Memory Usage: 21449520
> 200000. Inside Loop Memory Usage: 25643704 Inside Loop Peak Memory Usage: 25643824
> 300000. Inside Loop Memory Usage: 34032312 Inside Loop Peak Memory Usage: 34032432
> 400000. Inside Loop Memory Usage: 34032312 Inside Loop Peak Memory Usage: 34032512
>  Final Memory Usage: 17250856 Final Peak Memory
> Usage: 34032512

The best I have been able to come up with so far is using SplFixedArray in the following way:

```
$source_array = array_fill( 0, 500000, [ 'col1' => 'val1', 'col2' => 'val2', 'col3' => 'val3', 'col4' => 'val4', 'col5' => 'val5',] );
echo "Initial Memory Usage: ". memory_get_usage()  .' Peak Memory Usage: '. memory_get_peak_usage() ."<br>\n";

$source_array = SplFixedArray::fromArray( $source_array );
echo "Pre-Loop Memory Usage: ". memory_get_usage()  .' Pre-Loop Peak Memory Usage: '. memory_get_peak_usage() ."<br>\n";

$destination_array = new SplFixedArray( count( $source_array ) ); //This reduces peak memory by about 20-30%.
foreach( $source_array as $key => $row ) {
    $destination_array[$key] = $row; //Assume some manipulation of $row here.

    //$source_array[$key] = null; //Causes peak memory to increase.
    //unset( $source_array[$key] ); //Causes peak memory to increase
    if ( $key > 0 && $key % 100000 == 0 ) {
        echo "  $key. Inside Loop Memory Usage: ". memory_get_usage()  .' Inside Loop Peak Memory Usage: '. memory_get_peak_usage() ."<br>\n"; //Peak memory usage is double initial memory usage.
        gc_collect_cycles();
    }
}
unset( $source_array );
echo "Final Memory Usage: ". memory_get_usage()  .' Final Peak Memory Usage: '. memory_get_peak_usage() ."<br>\n"; //Peak memory usage is double initial memory usage.
```

> Output:
>
> Initial Memory Usage: 17250920 Peak Memory Usage: 17251016
> Pre-Loop Memory Usage: 8473216 Pre-Loop Peak Memory Usage:
> 25254608
> 100000. Inside Loop Memory Usage: 16477064 Inside Loop Peak Memory Usage: 25254608
> 200000. Inside Loop Memory Usage: 16477120 Inside Loop Peak Memory Usage: 25254608
> 300000. Inside Loop Memory Usage: 16477120 Inside Loop Peak Memory Usage: 25254608
> 400000. Inside Loop Memory Usage: 16477120 Inside Loop Peak Memory Usage: 25254608
>  Final Memory Usage: 8473272 Final Peak Memory
> Usage: 25254608

While a ~30% improvement over the original is decent, I feel as though I should be able to do this with a near zero peak memory increase. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you try `json_decode(json_encode($var))` ?

Comment: True. Is there any absolute need to duplicate the array? (Unless you are doing some R&D)

Comment: Yes, the $source_array is being processed row-by-row. While the $destination_array would not be a 1:1 duplicate in the real-world, for this exercise its essentially duplicated.

Comment: I should clarify that the $souce_array in the question is just an example. In the real-world its data from an external source and cannot be programmatically generated.

Comment: Why don't you read in the records one by one and process it directly? Instead of keeping all in memory you can store it directly into a database.

Comment: Unfortunately in this case the data has already been read in from the database and gone through several iterations of processing in memory and this question relates to another one of those iterations.

Comment: Ok, but why not storing back instead having both in memory? Or directly mutating the original instead of a copy?

Comment: Writing back to the DB or to disk would be substantially slower and overall be a step backwards compared to doubling memory usage.

Mutating the original doesn't make sense since the processing is relatively complex and not a direct row-by-row result. For example 50K rows may come in, and 100K out, or 10K out.

Comment: 2 Solutions: a) Use a memory efficent language like C/C++/Rust b) Get more RAM :D - Having a high mem usage should also no big deal, because the OS can do paging.

Comment: Another idea: Rethink your workflow. Cut into more steps and use message queues.